# How does destructuring of borrowed data work at compile time?

Tags: rust, destructuring, coercion, borrow

I've been using destructuring to create references into nested data, just for practice. I created a method that uses destructuring to break apart a borrowed tuple:

```
fn print_strings((x, y): &(String, String)) {
    println!("x: {}, y: {}", x, y);
}

fn main() {
    print_strings(&("foo".to_string(), "bar".to_string()));
}
```

If I add `let () = x` to the first line of the `print_strings()` function, the compiler tells me that x has type `&String`. This led me to believe that this is an instance of *deref coercion*, that the compiler was translating the `&(String, String)` from `main()` into a `(&String, &String)` to be used in `print_strings()`.

But then I looked up the documentation for `tuple` and didn't find an implementation of `Deref`. So my question is, how does the compiler expand this code?

My hypothesis is that something like this happens:

```
fn print_strings(a: &(String, String)) {
    let x = &(a.0);
    let y = &(a.1);
    println!("x: {}, y: {}", x, y);
}
```

EDIT:

I suppose this can't be deref coercion because the signature of the function matches the arguments being passed in by `main()`

Comment: Not able to answer right now, but the proper search term is probably "match ergonomics". In this case, `(x, y): &(String, String)` seems to be sugar for `&(ref x, ref y): &(String, String)`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are passing to `print_strings()` a *reference* to a tuple, it's not possible to get a `String` in it. So when accessing an individual element of that tuple in `print_strings()`, a `&String` is pretty much the only thing it would make sense to get. I believe that sort of destructuring is handled by the compiler itself.